# Validate presence of fields from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

With the following associations:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visitor
  belongs_to :contact_point
  validates :contact_point, presence: true
end

class Visitor < User
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :contact_point, through: :profile
end

class ContactPoint < User
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :visitors, through: :profiles
end
```

Each `ContactPoint` has a email. When the visitor creates her profile using the following form, she needs to determine the profiles contact point using the email address belonging to `ContactPoint`. The contact point users are already created and the visitors should not be able to update `ContactPoint` model.

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.label 'Last Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= fields_for :contact_point, @profile.contact_point do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label 'Contact point email' %>
    <%= ff.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In `ProfilesController` I am passing parameters to profile model this way:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.create(profile_params)
end

def profile_params
  contact_point = ContactPoint.find_by_email(params[:contact_point][:email])
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
                          .merge(visitor_id: current_user.id, contact_point: contact_point)
end
```

With the above setup, when there is no `ContactPoint` with the provided email address, the `contact_point` variable will set to be `nil` and the validator can't distinguish whether the contact point email in the filled in from was empty or not.
Now, how can I add a validation to check the presence of this email address in `contact_points` table and show a custom error message?

Comment: `validates :contact_point, presence: true` should do the trick. Are you sure the record is being saved to the database?

Comment: The problem is that `contact_point = ContactPoint.find_by_email(params[:contact_point][:email])` sets contact_point_id to nil, when there is no contact_point with this email address. The other situation that contact_point_id will be nil is when that filed is empty in the posted form.  I need the  validator to distanguish between this two cases.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use a custom validation that checks if contact_pounts.email is blank? If yes, then return false.

EDIT:

My brain is functioning better now after some sleep. You can do this using rails. This is how I would do it.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visitor
  belongs_to :contact_point
  validates :contact_point, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_point
end

class Visitor < User
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :contact_point, through: :profile
end

class ContactPoint < User
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :visitors, through: :profiles
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

What is going on here? We accept nested attributes for the association (ContactPoint) from Profile, so we can pass them through the @profile form you have to the controller. The models will handle the validation and set the error messages accordingly.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Could you give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it yourself in your controller, something like:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.create(profile_params)
  if !@profile.contact_point 
    if params[:contact_point][:email].present?
     @profile.errors.add(:contact_point, 'No contact with found')
    else
     @profile.errors.add(:contact_point, 'Please provide an email')
    end
    render :new
  end

end
```